# How to review low quality posts

Tags: support, question-quality, reviewing

While reviewing low quality posts, I have had the same problem multiple times.

As an exemple, I had to review [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140121/overflow-handling-application). The four choices are 1) Edit 2) Close 3) Delete 4) Ok.

As it is shown by the downvotes, the question seems indeed to be of low quality. However, the quality is not low enough to be closed or deleted (it is not spam or obvious duplicate). I can't really edit the question as I don't really know how to improve it (only OP knows how to do it).

My question is: in this case, is it expected to just leave a comment (and not if others have already done it) and click "seems OK", like I would do with First posts review (even though the question does **not** seem OK)?

Comment: If you're really not sure, you could just skip it and make it someone else's responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

There are several closing reasons:

[image]

In this case, "needs details" would be an appropriate choice, IMHO.

Note that closing does not necessarily imply "poor quality": an offtopic question can be a great one, or there can be multiple good questions (closed as "needs more focus").

That said, if you don't think a closing reason applies, nor do you want to downvote, I think you concluded that the question is "okay". And that's, pardon the pun, okay.